# How to get input element value by its index number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 input with same id
how to get the 2nd input value for example?
I use `eq()` and `nth-child()`, doesn't work

```
console.log($("#txtItemQuantity:eq(2)").val());
```

Note: I want to use id as the identifier, not class

HTML

```
<div class="masterItem">
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span><input id="txtItemName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span><input id="txtItemQuantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span><input id="txtItemName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span><input id="txtItemQuantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span><input id="txtItemName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span><input id="txtItemQuantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `same id` ID should be unique use class instead

Comment: `i have 3 input with same id` Id should always be unique. Use data-id instead.

Comment: `console.log($("input:eq(2)").val());` But `ID must be unique`

Comment: Tell this customer required, and avoid downvotes!

Comment: you can do both way but can't use same id tow or more time.

Comment: give the HTML please.

Comment: If your id is not unique your HTML is invalid. This will likely break jquery and any CSS3. Fix your HTML first.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak thank you, appreciated. i wont submit a stupid question if i know the answer, i still learning jquery from zero... don't know why someone downvote my question.

Comment: @akauts Because you are asking invalid and obvious concept in jquery

Comment: @FrayneKonok html updated, please what is the proper way to get the 2nd #txtItemQuantity

Comment: @akauts, checkout me in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281385/how-to-get-input-element-value-by-its-index-number/36281657#36281657)

Comment: @akauts you want the second quantity??

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ID must be unique. It cannot repeat.

You can select using attribute id, like

```
$('[id="txtItemQuantity"]').eq('1')
```

**Working Demo**

```js
alert($('[id="txtItemQuantity"]').eq('1').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input tpye="text" id="txtItemQuantity" value="1">
<input tpye="text" id="txtItemQuantity" value="2">
<input tpye="text" id="txtItemQuantity" value="3">
```

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: is it wrong if i insist to use id than class in this case, apparently it still has a solution? thank you again for your excellent solution Sir.

Comment: And my function to load array work like a charm! thank you sir.  

    $.each(e.vntret,function(a,b){$('[id="txtItemQuantity"]').eq(a).val(b.item_qtyorder);
     });

Comment: Yes. it is always good to use a class where ever you are compelled to use same Id. If you are changing it to Id you can modify my answer like `$('[class="txtItemQuantity"]').eq('1')`

Comment: looping using `.each()` is also fine

Comment: this **still** has invalid markup. Just because you can work around the invalid markup doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody is providing the correct solution here. Your underlying issue is your **invalid markup**. [No two elements in your HTML should have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611975/542251). To do so breaks the W3C conventions and will produce **unpredictable results**. Not just here but in other things too.

Change your markup so that the id is unique and add a class, then select by this:

```
<div class="masterItem">
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span>
                    <input id="txtItemName1" class="txtItemName form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span>
                   <input id="txtItemQuantity1" class="txtItemQuantity form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span>
                         <input id="txtItemName2" class="txtItemName form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span>
                         <input id="txtItemQuantity2" class="txtItemQuantity form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row oItem">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Name</span>
                          <input id="txtItemName3" class="txtItemName form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span>
                        <input id="txtItemQuantity3" class="txtItemQuantity form-control" placeholder="Quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

shortened:

```
<input id="txtItemName1" class="txtItemName form-control" type="text">
```

now just tweak your jquery selector (from your original question) to use the class selector (`.`) not the id selector (`#`).

```
console.log($(".txtItemQuantity:eq(2)").val());
```

FYI, because you have not provided names and because your input's share the same id the results posted back (when the form is posted) will also be unpredictable. Fix your underlying issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log($("[id^=txtItemQuantity]").eq(1).val());
```

Comment: `eq` always start with 0 index, so you have to use eq(1) for getting the second input of quantity.

Comment: Now its fine, and looks great.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle link goes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/s9oo4oL8/)

updated fiddle link with your HTML [link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/s9oo4oL8/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="txtItemQuantity">
  <input value="1">
  <input value="2">
  <input value="3">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var res = $("#txtItemQuantity input:nth-child(2)").val();
alert(res); // result 2
```

Comment: thanks, i saw this in jquery learning page. how about in my case? would you please see my html (updated), thanks

Comment: wait, let me check and do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this: `console.log($("#txtItemQuantity").eq(1).val());`
Dont' forget, count starts from 0

Comment: I doubt this will work because if you had 3 elements with the same id the markup would be invalid, thus likely breaking jquery

Comment: Well of course it will not work if you have 3 elements with the same id. The idea about id is to be unique. Otherwise you can't use eq, or you can maybe but is not ideal

Comment: Well sorry then :)

Comment: Question is: `I have 3 input with same id how to get the 2nd input value for example?`. My answer is good for what he asked. All answers are good ;)